# DMA operations on platform device

Tags: arm, linux-device-driver, dma

I am writing a device driver for altera arm board. Instead of using a Device Tree I used platform_device_alloc and platform_driver_register for setting my plaform device.

The thing is that my device should use the dma api. The DMA hooks are located at dev_archdata and the method to set them located [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mm/dma-mapping.c#L2077) . 
platform_device_alloc calles arch_setup_pdev_archdata that does nothing in ARM case. For PPC arch it [sets](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/kernel/setup-common.c#L747) this thing exactly.

So it seems that i should set it manually with arch_setup_dma_ops ?

Comment: You are starting the question from words 'writing a device driver', but the rest is about platform code (which is under arch/arm/). I guess, you have to look to the existing drivers for Altera and amend your question.

Comment: I am indeed writing a driver which uses the platform device API, and its not clear to me if I can use the DMA operations (dma_map_single etc..) on its struct device after the allocation and registration with the methods I mentioned. arch_setup_pdev_archdata  does nothing in ARM case so it seems invalid. All altera drivers uses the DT which seems to set this thing. I just wanted to be sure that I am not mistaken

Comment: It depends how 'special' your device is - if you do nothing you'll get the standard non-coherent DMA ops by default, but you'll still need to set a DMA mask manually (I think). If your device is hardware-coherent, or has some address offset, or other complications, and you really can't write a DT-based driver to let the existing code handle all this for you, then take a look at `of_platform_device_create()`, because that's essentially what you'll be duplicating.